# Show product name instead of product id in cart using php

Tags: php, html

I made a add to cart functionality by watching a tutorial. My problem is that when i click on add to cart button in my product page it shows the product id in cart page instead of the name. Here is my product page php code:

```php
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET["pro_id"])) {
  $proid = $_GET["pro_id"];
  if (!empty($_SESSION["cart"])) {
    $acol = array_column($_SESSION["cart"], "pro_id");
    if (in_array($proid, $acol)) {
      $_SESSION["cart"][$proid]["qty"] += 1;
    } else {
      $item = [
        "pro_id" => $_GET["pro_id"],
        "qty" => 1,
      ];
      $_SESSION["cart"][$proid] = $item;
    }
  } else {
    $item = [
      "pro_id" => $_GET["pro_id"],
      "qty" => 1,
    ];
    $_SESSION["cart"][$proid] = $item;
  }
} ?>
```

Here's my product card code:

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Laptop</h5>
    <p class="card-text">$200</p>
    <a href="index.php?pro_id=2" class="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then my cart page where it shows purchased products:

```php
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) :
  $i = 1;
  foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $cart) :
?>
  <tr class="text-center">
    <td><?php echo $i; ?> # </td>
    <td> Product <?= $cart['pro_id']; ?></td>
    <td>
```

Let me know how do i display the product by it's name and also if it's possible to display the product price in cart page too.

Comment: I don't see where you have stored your product names? It looks like they simply don't exist.

Comment: How do i store my product names and then call it? I've not learned php much so i still can't write it correctly. Hope you understand

Comment: You're currently learning to work with arrays. You could store product names in such an array. The keys to the array would be the product ids and the values would be the product names. Then when you need a name you can simply do `$productName = $productNames[$productId];`.

Comment: I see a lot of abbreviations in your code, like `proid` and `acol`. This is a very old, and wrong, way of programming. Names should help the reader understand what the code does. So `productId` is better than `proid`. `$acol` is even worse, because this refers to the way the value was created: By using the function `array_column()`. It should refer to what the value represents. Something like `$sessionItem`. Don't be afraid of using somewhat longer names. [Choosing good names](https://programmingduck.com/articles/naming) is the very first thing I teach people who learn to program.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add your product details in any storage (MYSQL) and retrive it. Then your structure for product will be like this.

Here assuming that your `prod_id` is `1`.

```
 `$productDetails[1]['productName'] = 'Product 1';`

 `$item = [
  "pro_id" => $_GET["pro_id"],
  "pro_name" => $productDetails[$_GET["pro_id"]]['productName']
  "qty" => 1,
  ];`
```